# Inexplicable behavior by Internet Explorer with FancyBox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I have implemented FancyBox (same version, files and everything) in 2 of my websites:

1. http://multiformeingegno.it
2. http://bombacarta.com/le-attivita/bombafoto/

Everything works fine in the first website with every browser (including IE), fancybox loads properly and it's ok. In the second website with IE if I click on the thumbnails after the 3 big images, instead of opening Fancybox, IE goes to the thumbnail url!! I can't understand why!! The links are:

```
<a href="BIG IMAGE URL" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
   <img src="THUMB URL" style="margin-right:5px;border:none" alt="" width="150" height="150"/>
```

Everything should work as expected (I have 0 errors on JS console and it is THE SAME FANCYBOX IMPLEMENTATION, SAME FILES AND EVERYTHING)! The thing I can't explain is WHY THE HELL Internet Explorer goes to the thumb URL when the  links to the big image!!

Of course everything works properly with ALL other browsers (including Safari Mobile and Android browser)!!!

Comment: I do not have IE to test it myself since I am on Ubuntu so I can't answer this correctly. But maybe it's an issue of IE having a longer time to load the page. Try opening it with IE and wait a while until everything is loaded in the page and then click the thumbnails.

Comment: Are you sure custom data attributes work in IE, like data-fancybox-group? Maybe you can try adding an id called the same thing to the <a tag

Comment: Absolutely nothing is inexplicable when it comes to IE. It's garbage. Nevertheless, we are often forced to support it anyway. Is there anyway you could create a JsFiddle that exhibits the same behavior? If you can't get it to do the same thing then that might help you fix it, if you can get the same behavior then maybe a fellow Overflower (is that what we're called?) can help you find the problem.

Comment: The strange thing is that on the first website (multiformeingegno.it , on the home page) fancybox works properly with IE too (Adam Hoke: so I presume that custom data attributes work in IE..)!! So strange..!

Dan: Uhm.. I don't think it's the problem! The page load is really fast, the strange thing is that instead of pointing to the <a> URL, IE goes to the <img> URL!

@John: Unfortunately I'm not able to do that.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your sites above really works fine with IE7. Fancybox pops up but there is not gallery functionality (at least with IE7).

Your site is using a modified version of fancybox: 
http://bombacarta.com/wp-content/themes/raymond-31/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js

I just updated it to the latest version from [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) website (including the css file) and it works as it should in all browsers, including IE7+

Check demo http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/bombafoto.html

The version of fancybox I used on the sample above (if you want to compare): 
http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancybox2.0.6/jquery.fancybox.pack.js

I guess something went wrong in the clone process.

Comment: Thank you JFK!! My version is modified just in one part to allow me to have a more long title:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245060/title-in-more-than-1-line-for-fancybox-2-0-6

Do you know what's causing the problem..? Thanks!! :D

EDIT: Oh, you were helping me in the other topic!! :P

Comment: I changed my page with YOUR scripts.. but it still doesn't work!!! :o
http://pastebin.com/0qBLZH0t

Comment: Actually it's the SAME page! This bombacarta.com/le-attivita/bombafoto/ and this: http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/bombafoto.html

I don't know why it doesn't work!!! :( :(

Comment: It's not the same page. I copied your code into my demo page and just changed the reference to the fancybox files.

Comment: I think I understood the problem. It's CloudFlare's fault. If you visit the page from this URL it works with IE too (CF is disabled):
http://direct.bombacarta.com/le-attivita/bombafoto/

:o :o